# xslt 2 copy parent element based on input array with loop

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog>
    <changeSet id="1" author="a">
        <createTable tableName="TABLE1">
            <column></column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="2" author="A">
        <createTable tableName="TABLE2">
            <column></column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="3" author="A">
        <createTable tableName="TABLE3">
            <column></column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="4" author="A">
        <createTable tableName="TABLE4">
            <column></column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

This is my xslt:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="tables" select="('TABLE1','TABLE4')"/>

    <xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
        <xsl:for-each select="changeSet/createTable">
            <xsl:if test="@tableName=$tables">
                <xsl:value-of select="../changeSet"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I'd like to select entire `changeSet` elements in which the tableName attribute will match one of `$tables` array value. So in this case there should be output like:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="a">
    <createTable tableName="TABLE1">
        <column></column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="4" author="A">
    <createTable tableName="TABLE4">
        <column></column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

I'm using saxon 9.8he for transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `xsl:value-of` which only outputs the string value of a node, you should use `xsl:copy-of`. And you also need to just select `..` to get the parent (doing `../changeSet` will try to get a sibling element named `changeSet`):

```
<xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
    <xsl:for-each select="changeSet/createTable">
        <xsl:if test="@tableName=$tables">
            <xsl:copy-of select=".."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Note you can simplify it to this...

```
<xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
    <xsl:for-each select="changeSet/createTable[@tableName=$tables]">
        <xsl:copy-of select=".."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Or even just this...

```
<xsl:template match="databaseChangeLog">
    <xsl:copy-of select="changeSet[createTable/@tableName=$tables]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nice one... I will accept it immediatelly when it will be possible (in 5 minutes :D). Can you please tell me one more thing? I am currently using  `http://www.example.com` as namespace in source xml. So for that I've added `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.example.com"` to `xsl:transform` and `copy-namespaces="no"` to `xsl:copy` however the default `xmlns=...` is still copied. Is it possible to disable this also?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188403/how-to-avoid-all-namespace-occurrence-in-output-by-writing-a-single-statement-in. Instead of using `xsl:copy-of` use `xsl:apply-templates` and add in the templates shown in that question